# Squared Differential Within Integral, Unrecognized Integration Trick

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was in my PDEs class this morning and was a little confused by an integral trick used by my professor once the PDE had been simplified to an ODE. It goes as follows:

$$g^\prime + \left[ 1 + g^2 \right] \frac{g}{r} = 0$$

$$\frac{g^\prime}{g(1+g^2)} = - \frac{1}{r}$$

$$\int \frac{dg}{g(1+g^2)} = - \int \frac{dr}{r} = - \ln |r| + c_1$$

$$\int \frac{dg}{g(1+g^2)} = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{dg^2}{g^2(1+g^2)} = \frac{1}{2} \int \left[ \frac{1}{g^2} - \frac{1}{1+g^2} \right] dg^2$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} \ln \left[ \frac{g^2}{1+g^2} \right] = - \ln |r| + c_1$$

$$\frac{g^2}{1+g^2} = \frac{c_1}{r^2}$$

I've never seen a squared differential term within an integral, and am not particularly sure how this was obtained in Equation Line (4). Is there a name for this type of trick and when can it be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a squared differential, but a differential of a square: $\mathrm{d}(g^2)$, not $(\mathrm{d}g)^2$. This said, you have that $\mathrm{d}g^2 = 2g\, \mathrm{d}g$, so you pass from the first to the second integral in the fourth line, simply by multiplying and dividing by $2g$.

The "trick" (which I don't think has a particular name) of writing $\mathrm{d}g^2$ instead of $2g\,\mathrm{d}g$ is essentially equivalent to noting that the integral is solved by the change of variable $g^2=f$; indeed, with the trick you recognise that you are integrating a function of $g^2$ with respect to $g^2$, which is the same conclusion you'd end up with using that change of variables.

Comment: Got it. Would it be wrong to think about this as equivalent to u-substitution, just without doing it explicitly?

Comment: @JacobIvanov, I would definitely not be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$$g^\prime + \left[ 1 + g^2 \right] \frac{g}{r} = 0$$
$$g'r +g=- g^3$$
This is just Bernouilli's differential equaton:
$$(gr)'=-g^3$$
$$\dfrac {dgr}{dr}=-\dfrac {g^3r^3}{r^3}$$
$$\dfrac {dgr}{g^3r^3}=-\dfrac {dr}{r^3}$$
Integrate.

Yes the trick is just a way to do a substitution here you can also apply this trick:
$$\dfrac 12\dfrac {d(gr)^2}{((gr)^2)^2}=-\dfrac {dr}{r^3}$$
$$\dfrac 12\dfrac {du}{u^2}=-\dfrac {dr}{r^3}$$
Where $u=(gr)^2$. You can also substitute simply $u=gr$.
$$\dfrac {dgr}{g^3r^3}=-\dfrac {dr}{r^3}$$
$$\dfrac {du}{u^3}=-\dfrac {dr}{r^3}$$